# Permission is denied by Windows in VMware in Ubuntu

Tags: permissions, windows, vmware, shared-folders

I am sharing a Windows folder with an Ubuntu guest OS in VMware. When I edit the file that is located in the shared folder of Windows in Ubuntu, it gives a `permission denied` error in the below screenshots.

[image]

[image]